# Product Out of Stock Subscription in not working in product listing page in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, javascript

I'm using Business King Product Out of Stock Subscription ([Link here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-out-of-stock-subscription.html))

to develop product out of stock alert subscription. Its working fine in product details page but it s not working on product listing page(list.phtml). Actually I'm keeping a from for every product who is out of stock.And in the browser console its showing `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` error.  Here is my code:

```
<ul>
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>          
                <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?> home_prod_list_list">
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                        <?php $_imgSize = 210; ?>
                        <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
                             src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image', $_product->getFile())->keepFrame(false)->resize(250,310); ?>"
                             alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                    </a>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
        var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
    </script>
                    <div class="own_share">
                    <?php $_storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(); ?>
                        <?php $_isActive = Mage::getStoreConfig('outofstocksubscription/mail/active', $_storeId); ?>
                        <?php if(!$_product->isSaleable() && $_isActive): ?>
                             <?php $_url = $this->getUrl('outofstocksubscription') ?>
                            <button class="own"></button>
                            <button class="share" onclick="ShowSocialMedia(jQuery(this));"></button>
                            <div id="out_of_stk">
                            <form action="<?php echo $_url ?>" name="productAddToCartForm" method="post"  id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
                            <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                        <input type="text" id="subscription_email" name="subscription_email"  style="width:100px;" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" />                   
                        <button class="subscribe_btn" type="button" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this);"></button>

                        </form>

                        </div>

                        <?php else :?>
                        <?php $_url = $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product); ?>
                        <form action="<?php echo $_url ?>" name="productAddToCartForm1" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?> style="display:inline;vertical-align:top;">
                            <button class="own" onclick="productAddToCartForm1.submit();" ></button>
                            </form>
                            <button class="share" onclick="ShowSocialMedia(jQuery(this));"></button>


                        <?php endif; ?>             

                </li>

                <?php 
                    $rowsCounter++;

                    ?>

            <?php endforeach ?>
            </ul>

            <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
                var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
                productAddToCartForm.submit = function(){
                        if (this.validator.validate()) {
                                this.form.submit();
                        }
                }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
        //]]>
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note `var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');`  assumes there is one form at the page, however there are many forms.  May be the code contain more logical errors I do not see at the moment, as it assumes we are at the product edit page.